# How do I make a reference to the selected value of a "select" list when the "options" are not static?

Tags: javascript, select

I have a simple question. I have a select list like this:

```
var myarray = ["one", "two", "three"];
var container = document.createElement("select");  
for (var i = 0; i < myarray.length; i++) {
    var element = document.createElement("option");
    var textlabel = document.createTextNode(myarray[i]);

    if (element.nodeValue == "two") { 
        element.selected = true;
    }

    element.appendChild(textlabel); 
    container.appendChild(element);
}
document.body.appendChild(container);
```

I have two questions about it:

1) I am pretty sure that the element that should be selected right now is "two"... isn't it?

2) Since the `option` elements are being created dinamically inside a loop (there are no three different option variables for me to play with, but just one that gets renewed as the loop goes forward), how do I reference the selected one for future uses?

For example, imagine that later on I get user input, and according to that input I want that this list has as a selected item, "three".

Thank you for any help! Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8zTHh/) if you want to use it...

Comment: `container.value` will give you the currently selected value.

Comment: You can also use `container.value = "two";` to select the "two" option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1) I am pretty sure that the element that should be selected right now
>   is "two"... isn't it?

No, it's not: you check element.nodeValue, while in fact you should've been checking `textLabel`'s one - or just the content itself:

```
if (myarray[i] === 'two') {
  element.selected = true;
}
```

> 2) Since the option elements are being created dinamically inside a
>   loop (there are no three different option variables for me to play
>   with, but just one that gets renewed as the loop goes forward), how do
>   I reference the selected one for future uses?

See, `<select>` elements has two useful properties: `options` (which contains all the options in it, and is updated dynamically) and `selectedIndex`. You can combine them to get the selected option:

```
container.addEventListener('change', function() {
   console.log(this.options[this.selectedIndex]);
}, false);
```

But if what you want is to know the *value* of selected element, that's even easier - with `container.value`.

> For example, imagine that later on I get user input, and according to
>   that input I want that this list has as a selected item, "three".

That's piece of cake if you know the position of the option that corresponds to this: just use selectedIndex property again:

```
container.selectedIndex = 3;
```

Comment: Thank you, I see it was quite simple. Now I know a bit more! Well explained.

Answer (score 1):

Just change the following in the `for` loop to fix the selection problem:

```
if (myarray[i] == "two")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `console.log` (on chrome or firefox with firebug) to debug your script :

Try [this](http://jsfiddle.net/8zTHh/3/) :

```
var myarray = ["one", "two", "three"];
var container = document.createElement("select");
container.id = "mySelect" ;  
    for (var i = 0; i < myarray.length; i++) {
        var element = document.createElement("option");
        var textlabel = document.createTextNode(myarray[i]);

        element.appendChild(textlabel);   

        if (element.value == "two") { 
            element.selected = true;

        }

        container.appendChild(element);
    }
        document.body.appendChild(container);
```

in order to refer to your selected element you should give your select element an id and access to it like below:

```
el = document.getElementById('mySelect');
el.selectedIndex ; // give you the selected index
el.options[el.selectedIndex]; // give you the value
```